# Taking screenshot from rtsp with C#

Tags: c#, rtsp

How can I take it with any library? I tried to do it with NReco but I've got some problems after this

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail("rtsp://admin:admin@27.51.226.250:832/cam/realmonitor", thumb1);
```

I can't take a snapshot from the stream. Actually I tried some vlc library with windows forms but something gone wrong with it too.

Comment: "Some problems", "something gone wrong"... so, what exactly?

Comment: i could not understand your question properly. I think screenshots can be taken using fireshot api - http://getfireshot.com/api.php